# Are there any infinite dimensional subalgebras of the Witt algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

The Lie bracket of elements of the Witt algebra is given by:

$[L_m,L_n]=(m-n)L_{m+n}$

Are there any infinite dimensional subalgebras of the Witt algebra that are not isomorphic to the Witt algebra itself?

Comment: the positive part? or some subalgebra like this.